# Set a default value for a hashtable param

Tags: powershell, param, powershell-4.0

Given the following PowerShell script header:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter()] [hashtable] $Mapping = ???
)
```

What to put instead of `???` to set a default table for the hashtable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
$Mapping = @{ "Key" = "Value" }
```

However, I've learned the hard way that you cannot pass a different value for this parameter. Calling powershell.exe with `-File` parses the parameter as string. So it is better to use a combination of a formatted string and [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx).